# javascript: Object and array manipulation i

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i really strongly to convert this array , can somebody help me out?

> [    {
>       "0":{"name":"a","available":"12","onOrder":"0",},
>       "1"{"name":"b","available":"3","onOrder":"0","},
>       "2"{"name":"c","available":"0","onOrder":"3"},
>       "3"{"name":"d","available":"2","onOrder":"2"}
>       } ]

how to map or convert to

> [    {"name":"a","available":"12","onOrder":"0",},
>   {"name":"b","available":"3","onOrder":"0","},
>   {"name":"c","available":"0","onOrder":"3"},
>   {"name":"d","available":"2","onOrder":"2"}
>       ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original example input has a few syntactical issues so I am not sure as to what the "array" and its elements look like. Making an assumption to make it syntactically compliant with the fewest modifications leads to the array in the working example below. Based on that input, using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is the simplest way to get the desired output.

```js
const arr = [{
  "0": {
    "name": "a",
    "available": "12",
    "onOrder": "0",
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "b",
    "available": "3",
    "onOrder": "0"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "c",
    "available": "0",
    "onOrder": "3"
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "d",
    "available": "2",
    "onOrder": "2"
  }
}];

console.log(Object.values(arr[0]));
```

#### EDIT: Updated to show ES2015 compatible solution

```js
const arr = [{
  "0": {
    "name": "a",
    "available": "12",
    "onOrder": "0",
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "b",
    "available": "3",
    "onOrder": "0"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "c",
    "available": "0",
    "onOrder": "3"
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "d",
    "available": "2",
    "onOrder": "2"
  }
}];

console.log(Object.keys(arr[0]).map(k => arr[0][k]));
```

Comment: this answer works only from es2017, unfortunately i use 2015, 
I have tried to solve it by using Object.keys (data). 
maybe not tried hard enough, thank you for the answer

Comment: @paraplu Made an update to show how you can use `keys` to get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
const arr = [
  { "0": {"name":"a","available":"12","onOrder":"0"} },
  { "1": {"name":"b","available":"3","onOrder":"0" } }, 
  { "2": {"name":"c","available":"0","onOrder":"3" } },
  { "3": {"name":"d","available":"2","onOrder":"2"} } 
];

const newArr = arr.map((item, index) => {
  return item[index];
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

More complex solution will be

```
const arr = [{
  '0': {
    'name': 'a',
    'available': '12',
    'onOrder': '0'
  },
  '1': {
    'name': 'b',
    'available': '3',
    'onOrder': '0'
  },
  '2': {
    'name': 'c',
    'available': '0',
    'onOrder': '3'
  },
  '3': {
    'name': 'd',
    'available': '2',
    'onOrder': '2'
  }
}]

const arr2 = arr.reduce((arr, item) => [...arr, ...Object.values(item)], [])

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: this answer works only from es2017, can you provide answer with Object.keys (data)?